# PHP many included files

Tags: php, html, header, indexing

Today I read some articles about compressing multiple JS and CSS files to one in order to lower the bandwith and HTTP requests. Is there analogical situation with the php files? Is it better to create master pages that include few PHP files(header.php,footer.php and etc)in order to have a well formatted and readable code than having just a large index.php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP is run on the server, and as such, only the resulting HTML is sent over to the client. Keep your files separated for clarity, it doesn't make a difference in the HTTP requests or bandwidth.

Comment: That is not *completely* true, as a large number of includes will cause a bit more filesystem activity. For the intents and purposes of this question though, this is completely correct, so +1

Comment: I knew as I was typing someone would point it out. I'll try to edit some clarity into it.

Comment: As Pekka states, that is not completely the case.  If you have a very large number of files included (large websites could easily go to a few hundred source files), then it could be an issue.  Extensions like eAccelerator are a help in those circumstances though.

Answer (score 1):

Like Xeon06 mentioned, PHP is a server-side script, and doesn't affect a bandwidth, which is size the of the content transferred through HTTP. Size of the bandwidth based on HTML, CSS, JS, Graphics, Flash and anything client-side files. Because browsers cache these kind of files, it reduces the bandwidth, because browser will get the file content from cache and not download from server again.

If I were in your shoes, I would still use includes for headers, footers or whatever is common in most pages. It just makes it easier to maintain a content and code. For example, if you have a feedback form on all pages and you want to edit a field name, link or something else, it's easier to edit one file instead of "Find and Replace" through all files you have, which doesn't work well anyways.